# Return users to launch activity after switching to other app

Tags: android, android-activity

My app requires the user to login before using and I want to make the user login again if they go to another app (ie my app is not visible). How can this be done, I'm not sure if using the onRestart method would do what I require?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe onRestart() or onStart() or even onResume(), have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in onRestart method. It's invoked when your app is recovering from onStop. Anyways you should consider this behavior. I don't know the context of your app, but in many cases do a login each time I come back to the app isn't a good user experience.

Comment: Perfect thanks, its for a banking application so would require a re-login each time.